# Misguiding error message on tag edit

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

I made an edit to the tags of [a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20335/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-schedule-autoexec-bat-like-command-in-linux)

I received a double note, one at the top, that my edit will pass a review process, and a second one at the bottom, which I'd like to discuss:

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - You have the privilege to retag questions; to suggest an edit please include a change to the title and/or the body as well

I guess there is a "don't" missing - `You don't have the privilege ...` - else it doesn't make much sense. Or am I wrong? Meanwhile, I find it annoying that I shall invent some edit reason in the body of the question.

I know similar discussions about only editing the title of a message and the 5 or 7 character rule from [general meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83441/156431) and I'm tired of it; this topic should be discussed over there, I think.

#### update

after Michaels hint to [this other thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/105594#105594), I think a rephrasing of the error message would be right.

Answer (score 4):

This was [intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit/97717#97717):

> I just changed it so you **must** suggest more than a tag edit, if you have retag rights.

If you have [retag rights](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) then you should [have a separate link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77406/people-between-500-and-2000-reputation-lost-the-ability-to-retag-questions/77409#77409) under the post specifically for editing tags -- you only use the "edit" link if you want to suggest an edit to the title/body. I think there's a post on meta pointing out how annoying that workflow is, but I'm having trouble finding it

<s>In any case, there does at least appear to be a typo in the error message</s> I just reread the error message and realized it is accurate, I just misread it. It's just telling you to use the retag link if you want to retag

Comment: Oh, yes, I see, and think I understand. If I only want to retag, I choose the retag link, but I used the edit-link. So editing the tags could be blocked, to force the user to use the retag-link, not the edit link, but then a user who wants to do both would be annoyed. But since the software detected everything: `a) I have retag rep. b) I did only a retag ` it could just accept the retag. :) I'm not sure about the name of this user-experience-anti-pattern: `Error 7! You have to push button X7`; displaying the errordialog, instead of performing what button X7 would do. retag: Feature request.

Comment: @user Agreed, and that's what [the question I linked was asking for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80345/145982). For some reason they implemented the opposite instead (rejecting the suggestion entirely) and marked it status-completed, so you might want to post your own feature-request about it (although waffles mentioned that [it's hard to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80345/retag-privilege-taken-into-account-when-proposing-an-edit#comment-246404), so it might get rejected)